# Getting error when load the bing map version 8

Tags: c#, bing-maps

when i run my code it show a script error dialog

```
"Error -Script error ,URL - http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=OnLoad"
```

OnLoad is function which i call to initialize the map

Url i used to get map in my html file  -

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=OnLoad' async defer></script>
```

Comment: Try this one. `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=release&callback=OnLoad' async defer></script>`. This is the one I used in my project only difference is that included the branch `branch=release`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to try. First make sure your network can reach the http://bing.com website. Second, make sure you have a function call OnLoad that is accessible to the map control to call. Verify spelling and that it al control doesn't try and call this function before it is available. Try adding async defer to your script tag and this will allow your other code to load a bit faster.

Comment: ,i have another problem.In bing maps 6.3 has a method call map.GetShapeByID(),how to use this method in bing map v8?